# SwiftUI Sidebar doesn't remember state

Tags: swiftui, sidebar, ipados, ios14, xcode12

I Have this app that uses the new **sidebar** introduced in iOS14 for iPad os but I can't figure out why it doesn't remember the state when its hidden

[image]

This is the sidebar struct

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Sidebar: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Binding var selection : Set<NavigationItem>
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            NavigationLink(destination: AgendaView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc).navigationTitle("Agenda"), label: {
                Label("Agenda", systemImage: "book")
            })
            .tag(NavigationItem.agenda)
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Subjects"), label: {
                Label("Materie", systemImage: "tray.full")
            })
            .tag(NavigationItem.subjects)
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Calendario"), label: {
                Label("Calendario", systemImage: "calendar")
            })
            .tag(NavigationItem.calendar)
            
            NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc).navigationTitle("Impostazioni"), label: {
                Label("Impostazioni", systemImage: "gear")
            })
            .tag(NavigationItem.settings)
            
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
}
```

for tagging the elements I use a custom struct called NavigationItem

```swift
enum NavigationItem {
    case agenda
    case calendar
    case ...
}
```

and here is where I placed the Sidebar in the content view, as you can see if the device is an iPad (detected using sizeClasses) I use the sidebar, otherwise if its an iPhone I use the TabBar

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    @State private var selection : Set<NavigationItem> = [.agenda]
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        
        if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
            TabBar(selection: $selection)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc)
        } else {
            NavigationView {
                Sidebar(selection: $selection)
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc)
                    .navigationTitle("Menu")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apples WWDC sample projects suffer from the bug as well. I filed a radar, you should probably, too. 

But a workaround for converting from sidebar to TabView would be great.

Comment: Yea, i saw that the Fruta app has the same "bug", I hope this get fixed soon if apple see this has a bug

Comment: On a side note, how do you set what is selected by default? I’m using a default version of sidebar and the initial state doesn’t have anything selected.

Comment: For the default selected item I use a custom Enum called `NavigationItem` as you can see from my code @State private var section ... and I made it coping the apple WWDC20 Fruta app that also does this thing to set the sidebar's default state, however this is not working because when i start the app there is nothing selected, hope apple fix this!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: nope, the issue is still there (I'm still on iOS14 btw)

Answer (score 1):

`List(selection: $selection)` for selection binding is macOS only. See this comment in the header:

```
/// On iOS and tvOS, you must explicitly put the list into edit mode for
/// the selection to apply.
```

As a workaround you could make the previously selected row appear bold, e.g.

```
 NavigationLink(
        destination: HomeView(),
        tag: Screen.home,
        selection: $selection,
        label: {
            Label("Home", systemImage: "house" )
        })
        .font(Font.headline.weight(selection == Screen.home ? .bold : .regular))
```

For more see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64523290/259521).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to be able to select multiple rows in your sidebar, change your `selection` definition to:

```
@Binding var selection: NavigationItem?
```

*Caveat: If you're interested in using the same `selection` variable for a `TabView`, that won't work. You'll need to define another property as `NavigationItem` that's **not** an optional.*